# É seguro usar o método String.concat() do JavaScript nos browsers atuais?

Tags: javascript, string

Eu estava observando que no JavaScript o objeto `String` possui um método chamado `concat()`. Serve para fazer a mesma coisa que o operador `+` faz.

```
"Meu nome é " + nome
```

Já com `concat()` ficaria assim:

```
"Meu nome é ".concat(nome)
```

Particularmente, acredito que com o método `String.concat*(` ficaria mais organizado. Mas gostaria de saber antes se é garantido que assim vai funcionar em todos os browser atuais.

Essa função é recente? Posso usá-la sem medo?

**Nota**: Para constar, essa pergunta está sendo feita no ano de 2016.

Comment: Jura que acha mais organizado? Seguro em que sentido? Não consigo imaginar um problema de segurança específico deste método.

Comment: Desculpa, quis dizer "seguro" no sentido de "assegurado que vai funcionar". kkkkk

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Este método não tem problemas de segurança, é suportado há muito tempo pelos navegadores.

Eu acho esquisito usá-lo em concatenações. Obviamente que o operador pode fazer coerção esquisita, mas isso é outro problema. A minha organização de código evita este tipo de coisa.

A [performance do método é ruim comparado com o operador](http://jsperf.com/concat-vs-plus-vs-join). Pior até que o `join()`. Pelo menos é o que deu no meu teste. Isto pode variar de acordo com a implementação.

A própria [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/concat) recomenda o uso do operador.

Comment: Ok. Mudei de opinião depois que vi os testes. Obrigado +1

Answer (score 3):

É seguro, a função é velha e você pode usar sem medo (já vem do standard 1.2 de js, isso é netscape 1997!) contudo não é recomendado pois a performance é lamentável se comparada com `+`, `+=` e `array.join`. Veja o teste: http://jsperf.com/concat-vs-plus-vs-join (de https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/concat#Performance).